# Tell when wcf client lost connection

Tags: c#, wcf, service, client

I have a few computers working as WCF clients and they are connected to a computer who works as the WCF service.
Now lets say one client connection is lost (i.e. the cable disconnects), How can I know that happened on the service side?
I tried to use the wcf callbacks events Closing/Closed but I did not get the call.
I am writing in C#.

Best Regards.
Adi.

Comment: Tell us more about your _service_.  Is it **pushing** data to clients?  Is it invoking the clients at some point (thus making the clients themselves services)?  Is your service `async`?  Not sure why your service needs to know that a client has abruptly disconnected.

Comment: @micky duncan  here is an example I wrote as a reply to peter's answer: "Lets say I have a chat between the clients and the service, the service has a gui that shows all the connected clients that i can chat with them. when a client connects the service gets a message and i can show it. if a client's cable disconnects i will not know that and in the GUI i will still see the client connected"

Comment: OK. Does your system need to work over the Internet or just a LAN? I wonder if there is something in the _[WCF P2P APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx)_?

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks dont work because your client cannot tell to service "i'am close connection with you".

What you need is heartbeat - periodic signal generated by your client to indicate normal operation. If service dont recieve this signal from one of clients in time it can guess that this client lost connection.

Also, you need a way to distinguish one client from another on service-side. For examle, every client can pass unique id in heartbeat signal.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, Heartbeat will definatly give me the answer to what I need. This will be my last result because I am looking for something more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your service should not care whether a network cable was disconnected. One feature of TCP is that unless someone is actively sending data, it can tolerate momentary interruptions in network connectivity.

This is even more true in WCF, where there are layers of extra framework to help protect you against network unreliability.

The main thing you would accomplish by attempting to detect disconnection of a client is reduced reliability and availability.

Comment: Lets say I have a chat between the clients and the service, the service has a gui that shows all the connected clients that i can chat with them. when a client connects the service gets a message and i can show it. if a client's cable disconnects i will not know that and in the GUI i will still see the client connected.