# WCF client becomes unusuable after internet is lost and reconnected

Tags: vb.net, wcf

On this previous question: [Tell when wcf client lost connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27340501/tell-when-wcf-client-lost-connection) One of the commenters states:

> Your service should not care whether a network cable was disconnected.
>   One feature of TCP is that unless someone is actively sending data, it
>   can tolerate momentary interruptions in network connectivity.
>
> This is even more true in WCF, where there are layers of extra
>   framework to help protect you against network unreliability.

I'm having an issue where this is not working correctly. I have WCF client that makes a connection to the server using a DuplexChannelFactory. The connection stays open for 3 minutes. I disconnect the client from the internet and reconnect. The client regains internet connection, however any calls made from the server to that client fail. Once the client reconnects it begins working again.

When I pull the plug on the internet, the client throws several exceptions but the channel is still listed as being in an open state. Once the connection is regained and I made a request from the server to the client, I get errors such as: **The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.**

Obviously if the request comes in when the client is offline it won't work, but I'm trying to get it so this channel will recover once the internet comes back without having to set up a new connection.

Should this be working as-is, based on the comment I listed above? Or is there something I need to change to make that actually work?

Comment: Are u using iis for hosting the service ?

Comment: On the client it is a Windows service, on the Server it is running through IIS.

Comment: Once a channel is faulted, it *cannot* be used again.  You have to abort that channel (connection) and open a new one.  The connection will stay open until a) it is explicitly closed, b) it timeouts or c) it faults (due to an error, a lost connection, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the channel you're trying to use is in a faulted state, and cannot be used any longer (as the error message indicates).

Your client needs to trap (catch) that exception, and then abort the current channel and create a new one.  WCF will not do that for you automatically, you have to code for it yourself.

You could also check the `CommunicationState` of the channel to see if it is faulted, and recover that way.

A final option would be to use the `OnFaulted` event handler, and when the channel is faulted, abort the channel and create a new one.

Comment: When these exceptions happen (when the internet is lost) the channel keeps reporting that it is still in an Open state. I also have the faulted event handler but it is not hit. For some reason the channel is never going into a faulted/aborted state, but the server side sees it as unusable. Do you know what could cause that?

Comment: Open just means the channel is open - it won't fault until its used and something goes wrong.  Is the channel to the service, or the channel from the service to the client?  It sounds like it might be the channel from the service to the client, in which case the service would need to handle the issue.

Comment: The channel is created on the client side. The server sends messages to the client through that channel. After the server attempts to communicate and gets the aborted error, the client side does not change. It still shows the channel as being open. I can't figure out the best way to detect this is happening on the client side so it can establish a new connection since it doesn't seem to think anything is wrong. Also based on that other question, it says that WCF services should be able to recover from temporary connection issues but I can't figure out how to make that work.